# Can an MSI installer be used for my executable/application to protect it during installation?

Tags: windows, security, installation, windows-installer

I want to deploy my application and was thinking of using an MSI installer since (from my understanding) it is a Single, Self Extracting Executable and also can be used to protect against DLL injection/protect the executable against DLL and/or EXE hijacking

Please correct me if I am wrong by assuming this; But if it is true, would someone please help me understand how it achieves this level of protection?

Thanks!
./best

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of that.  MSIs aren't an EXE, they are a document (database) handled by the Windows Installer service (msiexec.exe).  MSIs can be decompiled / viewed and don't hide anything.

MSIs can be signed (as can your application) that's about it for protection.